# AngularJS objects from web service

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-grid

I have a model defined on the client.

```
module Shared{
   export class HotelType{
      ID : number;
      Description : string;     
   }

   export class Hotel{
      ID : number;
      Type : HotelType
   }
}
```

I am using ngGrid to display the data.

What I do in my controller is very simple. Call the service and populate the data in the ng grid.

```
this.$scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'hotels',
            columnDefs: [{ field: 'ID', displayName: 'HotelID' },
            { field: 'Type.Description', displayName: 'Description' }],
            multiSelect: false,
            selectedItems: []
        };

ServiceManager.CallMethod(...)
            .success((hotels) => {
                this.$scope.hotels= hotels;
            });
```

All my hotels are of the same type. First row in the grid if fine.

10 - Best hotel

but the description in other rows is empty

11 -

12 -

When looking at what I get from my service I noticed I get an array of Hotels which is fine.
hotels[0].Type is a object with an $id = 2 and has all the properties (Description : "Best hotel" etc..)
But, hotels[1].Type only has one property $ref  "2".
And it is the same with all other types in other hotels.
I believe this is the reason why ng grid is displaying a description in only first row.

Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

I would like to see description in all of the row of ng grid..

Thank you.

Comment: If your data coming back from the server is consistent then this will work fine in the ng-grid, what are you seeing in the network response (check the chrome debugging tools or firebug).  If the format of the data is correct there then the grid works without a problem, you can test by building your expected array with JSON objects inside of it within your service (mock data) to see that the grid doesn't have an issue.

Comment: Thx... Web API was configured to preserve object reference...